# Shell script hangs forever grepping from file with name from "read $file"

Tags: bash, shell, syntax, scripting

I have my below shell script which searches for a string inside a file and returns the count. Not sure why it's getting stuck in the middle. Please can anyone explain.

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p "Enter file to be searched: " $file
read -p "Enter the word you want to search for: " $word

count=$(grep -o "^${word}:" $file | wc -l)
echo "The count for `$word`: " $count
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
luckee@zarvis:~/scripts$ ./wordsearch.sh
Enter file to be searched: apple.txt
Enter the word you want to search for: apple
^C
```

Comment: `read $file` is treating **the current value of `$file`** as the name of the variable to read into (sorta -- because it isn't quoted correctly, it's actually doing something even more complex than that). If that variable is empty, it ends up reading into the default variable of `REPLY`. `read file`, instead, reads into the variable named `file`.

Comment: ...by the way, http://shellcheck.net/ will detect that there's something wrong there (that you're trying to use the value for the variable `$file` before establishing it) automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`read` needs to be passed a variable *name*. `file`, not `$file`.

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p "Enter file to be searched: " file
read -p "Enter the word you want to search for: " word

count=$(grep -o -e "$word" "$file" | wc -l)
echo "The count for $word: $count"
```

What was happening previously is that your `file` variable was empty, so your code was running:

```
count=$(grep -o "^${word}:" | wc -l)
```

...with no input specified, so it would wait forever for stdin.

---

By the way -- you don't need `wc` for this; `grep` can emit a counter itself, using the `-c` argument (also called `--count` in the GNU implementation). If you want that counter to go by words rather than lines, one can use `tr` to put each word on its own line:

```
count=$(tr '[[:space:]]' '\n' <"$file" | grep -c -e "$word")
```

Comment: Ohh yeah ... how can I be so foolish ! Just a matter of touch which I had left long back. BTW, there's still a problem. The file I am using has content "This a test file for apple search. The script will search number of times apple is mentioned here. Finally it will print the apple number. " in which apple is mentioned thrice but the script prints 0. How can we overcome this issue ?

Comment: Your pattern (I assumed intentionally) expects the word to be found at the beginning of a line and followed by `:`. If that's *not* by intent... I'll edit.

Comment: (in `^${word}:`, the `^` restricts to matches only at the very front of the file, and the `:` restricts to matches where the word has a `:` directly after it).

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a ton @Charles Duffy for the quick turnaround !